# How to get object and lower hierarchical objects from a DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm new on DXL and working on something that is probably quite simple.
I would like to parse the current module, and get the following data for each object that has a given ID (calling IDNUM below) not empty: 
IDNUM - Object text - all text with a lower hierarchic level and the same thing for all objects liked to this one.

It will probably be easier to understand with the code. So far, it looks like that:

```
Object o 
Object ol
Link l
Module m = current Module

For o in entire(m) do{
 if (o."IDNUM" != ""){
   print o."IDNUM" "" 
   print o."text" "" 
   //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ALSO PRINT EVERY TEXT IN OBJECT "LOWER" THAN o
   for l in o --> "*" do{
    ol = target(l)
    print ol."text" "" 
    //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ALSO PRINT EVERY TEXT IN OBJECT "LOWER" THAN ol
   }
  }
}
```

Basically, I have the ID and title of both an object and the one liked to it, but not the text below. In other words, my code will "mimic" the function `right click>copy>copy with hierarchy`
 How can I do that? Unfortunately I didn't find anything very helpful.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sketch code you outlined:

```
Object o 
Object ol
Link l
Module m = current Module

For o in entire(m) do{
 if (o."IDNUM" != ""){
   print o."IDNUM" "" 
   print o."text" "" 
   //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ALSO PRINT EVERY TEXT IN OBJECT "LOWER" THAN o
   for l in o --> "*" do{
    ol = target(l)
    print ol."text" "" 
    //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ALSO PRINT EVERY TEXT IN OBJECT "LOWER" THAN ol
   }
  }
}
```

There are a few little syntax things that need to be changed here, but the big change is how you are handling linked items. Links 'live' in the source module, but they only store a limited amount of information, mostly the modules that are the source and target of the link, and the absolute numbers of the objects they touch. So you need to check if the module on the other side is open before you try and read text from it.

And since you are trying to go through the entire link structure, you'll need a recursive element to this.

I would probably end up with something like this:

```
//turn off run limit timer- this might take a bit
pragma runLim , 0 

Object o 
Module m = current Module

// Recursive function- assumes each object has a text attribute- will error otherwise
void link_print(Object obj) {
    print obj."text" "\n"
    Link out_link
    Object next_obj = null
    for out_link in obj -> "*" do {
        // Set the next object in the chain
        next_obj = target ( out_link )
        // This might return null if the module is not loaded
        if ( null next_obj ) {
            // Load the module in read-only mode, displayed and in standard view
            read ( fullName ( ModName_ target ( out_link ) ) , true , true )
            // Try and resolve out 'target' again
            next_obj = target ( out_link )
            // If it doesn't work, print a message so we can figure it out
            if ( null next_obj ) {
                print "Error Accessing Object " ( targetAbsNo ( out_link ) )""
            } else {
                //Iterate down structure
                link_print ( next_obj )
            }
        } else {
            //Iterate down structure
            link_print ( next_obj )
        }
    }
}


for o in entire(m) do {
    // Note that I cast the result of o."IDNUM" to a string type by appending ""
    if (o."IDNUM" "" != ""){
        print o."IDNUM" "\n" 
        // Recurse
        link_print(o)
        print "\n"
    }
}
```

Note! Depending on the size of your link structure, i.e. how many levels you have (and if there are any circular link patterns), this could be a pretty resource intensive task, and would be better solved using something other than "print" commands (like appending it to a word file, for example, so you know how far it got before it errored out)

Good luck!

EDIT:

Rather than head down recursively, this script will now go a single level but should report child objects.

```
 //turn off run limit timer- this might take a bit
pragma runLim , 0 

Object o 
Module m = current Module

// Recursive function- assumes each object has a text attribute- will error otherwise
void link_print(Object obj) {
    print obj."text" "\n"
    Link out_link
    Object next_obj = null
    Object child_obj = null
    for out_link in obj -> "*" do {
        // Set the next object in the chain
        next_obj = target ( out_link )
        // This might return null if the module is not loaded
        if ( null next_obj ) {
            // Load the module in read-only mode, displayed and in standard view
            read ( fullName ( ModName_ target ( out_link ) ) , true , true )
            // Try and resolve out 'target' again
            next_obj = target ( out_link )
            // If it doesn't work, print a message so we can figure it out
            if ( null next_obj ) {
                print "Error Accessing Object " ( targetAbsNo ( out_link ) )""
            } else {
                // Loop and report on child objects
                for child_obj in next_obj do {
                    print child_obj."text" "\n"
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Loop and report on child objects
            for child_obj in next_obj do {
                print child_obj."text" "\n"
            }
        }
    }
}


for o in entire(m) do {
    // Note that I cast the result of o."IDNUM" to a string type by appending ""
    if (o."IDNUM" "" != ""){
        print o."IDNUM" "\n" 
        // Recurse
        link_print(o)
        print "\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll try to use it as soon as possible and let you know if it works. But it looks promising

PS : yep, the "print" commande is placed here just to emphasis what I want to extract. I'll find a way to write into a word/notepad file later...

Answer (score 0):

Dear Russell (and everyone else)

I've just went through the piece of code you provided me and it works.... but not for what I'm looking for. It seems my explanation wasn't very clear. I'm sorry (I'm not a native speaker). 
I'm not looking to get all links, but just the `Object text` that is written just below the object pointed by the current link. 
Here is what my files look like

```
 object1 (with IDNUM) : "Title_doc_1"   --> (link) objectA "Title_doc_2"
    object2 : "some_text"                            objectB : "some_text"
    object3 : "some_text"                            objectC : "some_text"
```

(`object1` can point to many other `objectA` but I already deal with that.)

The code I provided above parses the "doc_1", and print `"IDNUM" "Title_doc_1" "Title_doc_2"`

What I'm looking for is to get, not only `objectA` but also `objectB` and `objectC` which are hierarchically below `objectA` (and `object2` and  `object3` too but it will ve the same process).

Hopping I made myself understood...

Comment: Ah, I see! Will edit my answer. You're looking for each 'child' object of the linked item.

Comment: I use what's in your aswer with ``level(o)`` and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.